# Does an orthogonal matrix always conmutes or anticonmutes with a matrix $J$ such that $J^2=-I$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, almost-complex

I was asked by my professor to show that if $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $J$ is a matrix such that $J^2=-I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix) then $$AJ=JA.$$

I think my instructor made a mistake. As a (very) particular case, I computed that $$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x) & \sin(x)\\
-\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin(x) & -\cos(x) \\
\cos(x) & \sin(x)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(x) & \sin(x)\\
-\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{bmatrix},$$ in this case $AJ=JA$. However, computing another example $$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ therefore in this case $AJ=-JA$. So the instructor made a mistake. However, this me question something:

*If $V$ is a vector space of finite dimension and $A \in \mathrm{O}(V)$, does it always holds that $AJ=\pm JA$? (It doesn’t matter if $\dim V$ is even or odd)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you have a linear map $J: V\to V$ so that $J^2 = -I$, then taking dterminant gives

$$ (\det J)^2 = (-1)^n,$$
where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. This already implies that $n$ is even.

And it is not always true that $AJ = \pm JA$: for example, take $n=4$ and let

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -I_2 \\ I_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$JA = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ AJ = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$